# FK over multiple columns of which one is already unique

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a pair of master-detail tables `masters(id, ...)` and `details(id, master_id, ...)` with `details` referencing `masters` via `details.master_id = masters.id`.

For optimization purposes, I want to add a nullable `masters.latest_detail_id` which would back-reference a specific detail row among existing detail rows of the master row.

Since not just *any* detail row is referable but only one of those that already belong to the given master row I want to leverage the database schema and create a FK like so: `(masters.latest_detail_id, masters.id) = (details.id, details.master_id)`. However, this requires me to create a useless unique key in `details` over `id, master_id`. This makes no sense as `details.id` is already unique.

I have the same problem with leveraging the DB schema to enforce multi-tenancy, to prevent cross-tenant linking (each table has a mandatory `tenant_id` and all FKs reference `id, tenant_id` which again requires me to create a useless UK).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: The only way to avoid thst is to do without the foreign key.